# Has az login stopped working in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: linux, azure, ubuntu, azure-cli

I have used the azure command line some months back without problems. Today I needed to use it again. Nothing has changed in my system, and I am still using the same organization.

I run `az login` from my terminal (Ubuntu 20.04) and I am shown a browser window. I login to my Azure account. The page replies with:

> You have logged into Microsoft Azure! You can close this window, or we
> will redirect you to the Azure CLI documents in 10 seconds.

The terminal then displays the authentication reply (a long json response). So far so good.

Now I try to do something with the azure cli, in this case trigger a pipeline:

```
az pipelines run --output table --organization https://dev.azure.com/MyOrg/ --project MyProj --name MyRepo --branch refs/heads/y/branch --open
```

But it complains with:

> Before you can run Azure DevOps commands, you need to run the login command(az login if using AAD/MSA identity else az devops login
> if using PAT token) to setup credentials.  Please see
> https://aka.ms/azure-devops-cli-auth for more information.

This was not the case some months back. What happened here?

### EDIT

This is my `az` cli:

```
» az --version
azure-cli                         2.34.1

core                              2.34.1
telemetry                          1.0.6

Extensions:
azure-devops                      0.18.0

Dependencies:
msal                              1.16.0
azure-mgmt-resource               20.0.0

Python location '/opt/az/bin/python3'
Extensions directory '/home/theuser/.azure/cliextensions'

Python (Linux) 3.8.12 (default, Mar  2 2022, 07:26:21) 
[GCC 9.3.0]

Legal docs and information: aka.ms/AzureCliLegal


Your CLI is up-to-date.

Please let us know how we are doing: https://aka.ms/azureclihats
and let us know if you're interested in trying out our newest features: https://aka.ms/CLIUXstudy
```

Comment: Version of az-cli?

Comment: @harshavmb version info added to question. I updated today (while trying to solve this problem), so it should be a recent version

Comment: Downgrade az-cli to `2.29.2` version & check again. [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/20529) is an open issue..

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the same ,to upgrade my `CLI version`  and it failed several times and now only got *succeed* the error might be you are getting due to some recent changes still going on with `2.34.1 version`.

[image]

[image]

Would suggest you use the old version of CLI and then check or, for Workaround you can use `az devops login` using **`PAT token`** .

You can refer the same document to `login with PAT` which one you are getting in an error .

For more information please refer this [***GitHub issue***](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/20529#issuecomment-989863373) as suggested by @*wiruzman*